# Why webextension installation failure?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am learning how to write webextensions.
so I'm copying "beastify" extension from [here](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/beastify) from scratch.

But my copied version's installation failure.
I don't know why installation is failure.

There are same directory structure, same meaning code, same picture file.

I suppose there are causes of installation failure in manifest.json.

my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Beastify",
    "version": 1.0,

    "description": "add a browser action icon to the toolbar. Click the button to choose a beast. The active tab's body content is then replaced with a picture of the choosen beast.",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/beasts-48.png"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/beasts-32.png",
        "default_title": "Beastify",
        "default_popup": "popup/choose_beast.html"
    },

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "beasts/frog.jpg",
        "beasts/turtle.jpg",
        "beasts/snake.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `version` must be string.
Please replace `"version": 1.0,` to `"version": "1.0",`.